# What is the drug dealer playing in the film Kick-Ass?

Tags: game-identification

In the scene where Hit-Girl first assists Kick-Ass, what is the drug dealer playing?

You only get a few seconds to see the game on screen.

The game is split screen (in the screenshot below, the red bar is the border of the top player, who has been killed in-game).

There are numerous clips on youtube if you don't have the film.

I have tried googling the game name but anything with `kickass` and `game` just gives me the Kick-Ass game as opposed to the game in this clip.

[image: Generic FPS]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1125798/movieconnections) says it is Call of Duty 4 : Modern Warfare

> Kick-Ass (2010)
>
> Razul and his goons are playing this game in the apartment when Kick-Ass enters.

All the transcripts I could find, [here 2 sources (PDF file)](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Kickass.pdf) for [movie transcripts](http://www.shadowandact.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/Kickass.pdf), all states he's playing CoD 4

> A depressing drug den in which RASUL - 19, cute but wasted -
> sits playing CALL OF DUTY 4 with some other THUG.

[CamelCase (see comment) found that CoD 4 wiki also mention being the game in the movie.](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_4:_Modern_Warfare)

According to [the Kick-Ass wikia, trivia section](http://kick-ass.wikia.com/wiki/Rasul) however, he's playing Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2.

> In the movie, Rasul is playing Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 on the Xbox 360, in the comics his counterpart originally plays an unnamed Spyro The Dragon game as the bouncer tells Kick-Ass but unlike the movie version, the gameplay for Spyro is not seen on the panel and is replaced with a generic design with a controller parodying Playstation.

Comment: See, that's what I thought too, but the killcam is wrong. http://i.stack.imgur.com/VUwvv.jpg There are red bands above and below. In the image, it only appears above. It would be nice if that trivia was cited in the Wiki...

Comment: @TheFaster that's because the red bar is the border of the top player, as the OP wrote.

Comment: @TheFaster - read my edit as the game is being played split screen. The top player has been killed.

Comment: @rasteve Ah, I see it now. Good catch. Definitely MW2.

Comment: They went through the effort of parodying the Playstation controller?  They should have also gave the woman the line "Can't you tell by my Bouncing Bettys?"

Comment: I also found that this COD4 wiki mentions that the game is in the movie: http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Call_of_Duty_4:_Modern_Warfare

Answer (score -3):

It is definitely Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare. They are playing split-screen on the multiplayer map called "Crash". The player on the bottom screen seems to be using the G36C assault rifle with a red dot sight attachment.